# Extract features till date of outcome or latest date

Tags: machine-learning, classification, data-transformation, data-mining, feature-engineering

let's say I have a project which involves predicting the likelihood of whether a specific project will meet their sales target or not.

So, I have 2000 project records from Jan 2020 to Apr 2023. Some of this have already met their sales target in different months of 2022 and some are still in progress. So, now I am in the process of extracting features for these projects and building a predictive model.

So, my question is, let's say I have a project_id = 2 which met the sales target on Dec 10th, 2022 and I have another project_id = 4 which is still ongoing (in progress) of meeting the sales target (has met only 40% of sales target).

So, now when I engineer features, should my features be made up of data till latest time point for both project_id = 2 and project_id = 4?

Or since project_id = 2 got over/met the target by Dec 10th 2022, should my values for features should only be till Dec 10th, 2022 for project_id=2? And for Project_id = 4, we can have values for features based on latest data till 21st Apr 2023.

But the problem is I have 2000 projects. So, for all these projects do I have to compute engineer features and their values based on the date when they met their target? Because each project could have met their target on different dates. So, I have to compute the values for each feature based on their outcome date/target met date? Am I right?